# Android Studio Emulator is not running

Tags: flutter, android-emulator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE1xp.png)
When I run the emulator inside the Android studio, it works well as in the picture above.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmMhm.png)
but, When running an emulator in vs code or running an emulator independently in an Android studio, the emulator does not run. how can i solve this problem?

i try to search the google. but there is not a solution

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the device is locked. Try pressing the power button on the emulator.
[image]

Comment: thank you for your answering. but, it didn't run. i wait a long time